# Remove self <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a litte bug, in my menu there's some links that has no hrefs (like My empty link).
If it has no href, i want to remove the  but keep the text.

this is what i got:

```
$('.mainmenu a, .mainmenu a *').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(!href)
    {
        console.log($(this).html());
        //Remove <a> from this element, how?
    }
});
```

help please?

Comment: By "has not href", do you mean `<a>` or `<a href>` or `<a href="">` Or all of those?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, in this case the href does not exsists at all. looks like <a>My Link</a>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unwrap the contents then

```
$('.mainmenu a:not([href])').contents().unwrap()
```

[:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to filter out elements without an `href` tag

[.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) returns a jQuery object that contains the contents - which is the text

[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) removes the anchor tag around it

Comment: This did the trick! Very nice!

Answer (score 4):

## Pure JavaScript

If you want some performance-based code, try this one out.

```
var emptyAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('.mainmenu a:not([href])');
var content = "";

for (var a in emptyAnchors) {
    if(emptyAnchors[a].nodeType == 1)
    {
        content = document.createTextNode(emptyAnchors[a].innerHTML);
        emptyAnchors[a].parentNode.insertBefore(content, emptyAnchors[a]);
        emptyAnchors[a].parentNode.removeChild(emptyAnchors[a]);
    }
}
```

### [Performance review](http://jsperf.com/jquery-unwrapping-vs-pure-javascript)

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LwnW7/6/)

---

## JQuery

Use JQuery [`$.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method. This get the selected DOMElement's textnode and extracts it from the element, then deleting the empty element.

```
$('.mainmenu a:not([href])').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().unwrap(); /* Will delete the tag but keep its content */
});
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LEdnb/2/)

**Note:** This one is pretty much an alternative to the selected answer, which is more efficient.

Comment: does not seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LwnW7/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Edited the code so it works as intended.

Comment: "Performance-based" code doesn't iterate over arrays using for var in :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the `:not` CSS3 selector.
2. Use the [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method.

---

```
$('.mainmenu a:not([href])').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Why each ? Just .remove();

Comment: use jQuery's unwrap()

Comment: As rid said, i want to keep the text. unwrap() did not work - a element is still there.

Comment: Try `replaceWith`, see updated answer.

Comment: Actually if someone gives the solution, delete your answer, don't copy it, especially if you do it in a less efficient way.

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LwnW7/2/

Answer (score 1):

One more solution replace the content of the parent with the content of the element to be removed `$(this).replaceWith($(this).contents())`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXbX2/7)

Comment: -1 This will destroy siblings as well. http://jsfiddle.net/YXbX2/1/

Comment: @CrazyTrain You are right. Changed to to `replaceWith` using [`$(this).replaceWith($(this).contents())`](http://jsfiddle.net/YXbX2/7/)

Comment: Be sure to update your answer so I can remove the down vote.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
$('.mainmenu a:not([href])').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.replaceWith($this.text());
});
```

Might be a little quicker :

```
$('.mainmenu a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('href') || $this.replaceWith($this.text());
});
```

Comment: Don't know why you would get -2 for this. You've already got my +1. One possible improvement would be to get rid of `.each()` and pass a function directly to `.replaceWith()` that returns the text. Just a  little more efficient that way.

Comment: By removing .each() you perform the replacement for each element which is not desirable if you do not use the first selector to filter links without href attribute. So yeah, that's true for the first option, but not for the second. EDIT : Actually it's not even true for the first one since the content of each link is likely to be different from the others.

Comment: You skipped over the part where I said to pass a function to `.replaceWith()`. http://jsfiddle.net/YXbX2/4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/YXbX2/6/

Comment: Ho okay i didn't know we could do that. replaceWith using a function looks a bit less intuitive though.